# External monitor works with one user account but not the other

Tags: kde, display, monitors

I have an Alienware aw3418dw external monitor and I'm running  Pop!_OS 19.04 , along with kde display manager.

I have two accounts on this computer, one for personal, one for work. The monitor works fine with the personal but with the work account the monitor never wakes up when the HDMI cable is plugged in.

If I reboot and login to the other (personal) account it does work. It also works during door and on the screen which I select the user account to login with, very strange.

I've tried:

```
cp --preserve=timestamps /home/personal/.config/monitors.xml  /home/work/.config/monitors.xml
```

I also went into Display settings and the monitor does not show up there.

This had no effect.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue for that single user account?

edit: here's that config file https://pastebin.com/ZrjsQ0EK

Comment: As user work, try a `cat /home/work/.config/monitors.xml` to make sure user work can happily read the config file ?

Comment: @steve yes it can read that. and here's the content of the file https://pastebin.com/ZrjsQ0EK

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the monitor config fixed it

```
xrandr --auto
```

Comment: Thanks, man! You saved me plenty of time.